# how to read LDAP error codes

Tags: error-handling, ldap

I am having trouble reading ldap error codes. Is there any method or an API to read ldap error codes/sub error codes.Right now I am parsing the exception message and getting the error code. I believe there will be a simple way of extracting codes?

Padur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a function called `ldap_errno()` that returns a string based on the error code.

There is also a comment that has a list of common LDAP error codes, dated April 11th, 2002 but very accurate: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-errno.php#20665

Other than this, you could write your own program/script to parse the error, since you now know what each code means.

Comment: Nice.I have used my own custom parser to read LDAP error codes.